# bash arithmetic expression: check for zero-valued variable

Tags: bash

I find this behaviour counter-intuitive:

```
v=0; ((v)) && echo K; v=1; ((v)) && echo J
```

echoes:

```
J
```

but generally `0` is *success*:

```
f() { return 0; }; if f; then echo W; fi
```

---

#### Explain the reasoning?

---

`man` page for `(( ))` says:

*If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.*

---

How best to check if a variable is zero using Arithmetic Evaluation?

Comment: A simplistic explanation is that one is a _numeric value_, the other is a _status code_. There is no reason to expect similarities in behavior or use just because both are represented by the same symbol at some point. (Pi and my office number both start with '3' but I've learned to clearly distinguish the two :-) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical way to test for 0 is `[ $something -eq 0 ]`, often written as `[ x$something = x0 ]`. (Using `=` is a string comparison but it is still valid syntax when the variable isn't set or is otherwise blank.) See `man expr`.

So,

```
q=0
if [ $q -eq 0 ]; then # or [ x$q = x0 ]
  echo yes, zero
fi
```

The `((expr))` syntax is a shortcut for the `let` command, and that command is simply defined to return `true` status when the expression is non-zero and false otherwise.

And neither `((...))` nor `let ...` are Posix commands, so some amount of *WTF?!* may be expected. It's just something the authors of bash either thought up or pulled in from some now-obscure earlier shell. (It seems to be in zsh.) It is not in [ash(1),](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sh%20%20NetBSD-current) aka [dash(1),](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) which is kind of the reference pure-Posix shell.

Comment: Why does this flip the entire mindset of `0` being _success_ around? Is there a canonical example of convenience? Historical reasons? Prevention against adverse effects?

Comment: Usually, there is just one way for a command to succeed, but many different ways it could fail. Using 0 for success, non-zero for failure allows different codes to indicate different types of failure.

Comment: The behaviour for arithmetics is the same as in C (i.e. non-zero being true).

Comment: @DigitalRoss: WTF, indeed. I agree.

Comment: I've always thought of `(( ... ))` as the POSIX-specified `$(( ... ))` construct with the `$` dropped, to create a stand-alone command (a statement instead of an expression, as it were). `let` may be borrowed from some dialect of BASIC for all I know.

Comment: Regarding 'The canonical way to test for 0 is `[ $something -eq 0 ]`' it might be noted it's even **more** canonical to use `[ "x$something" = "x0" ]` as in contrast to to the version given this won't either lead to an error if $something **contains spaces** or if $something **is empty**.

Comment: Try `[ $something -eq 0 ] && echo "yes"` both with `something="1 -o 2"` and after `unset something` to see examples where the suggested test will go haywire. While obviously no beauty `[ "x$something" = "x0" ]` will still return the correct result in both cases. I was to shy to edit, but maybe you want to add that in your post.

Answer (score 3):

One good reason to "flip" the meaning to `0` sucess any value **not** `0` not sucess is that you might want to indicate different error conditions.

Using `0` as failure this wouldn't be possible at all as any value != `0` would have been wasted to indicate sucess.

Given a numeric variable the best way to check if the value is `0` is to do exactly that:

```
((v==0))
```